Does clang support _Atomic Pointer Arithmetic
demo.c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
static int ia[2];
 static volatile _Atomic (int *) a = (int *) (&ia[1]);
 if ((a += (1)) != (int *) ((int *) (&ia[1]) + (1)))
         printf("1");
}

compile failed
<source>:5:9: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('volatile _Atomic(int *)' and 'int')
    5 |  if ((a += (1)) != (int *) ((int *) (&ia[1]) + (1)))
      |       ~ ^  ~~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1

Gcc is ok!
https://godbolt.org/z/fMqzoe4b5
Does clang support  _Atomic Pointer Arithmetic

a++ succeeds, as does atomic_fetch_add(&a, n).

I'm pretty sure the C standard requires a += n to work for _Atomic pointers.  I'd say this is a clang bug that should be reported.

Oh, I see you already did: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/116736

This is legal C code.  The fact that clang rejects it is a bug, reported in 2015 and still not fixed.
As a workaround, you can use ++a in this special case where you are adding 1, or for more general addition, you can use atomic_fetch_add which does work on pointers.  Note however that atomic_fetch_add returns the old value rather than the new value, so to get the equivalent of a += 5, you'd have to write something like
atomic_fetch_add(&a, 5)+5.
